# Spark tempTable issue, table does not exist? how to solve?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Env: Spark 1.6, Scala

Hi
I have created an empty dataframe [sessionTrend], and did unionAll with an existing dataframe[DF2, created from SQL Server database table], resulted dataframe, sessionTrend is working fine. But after registering sessionTrend dataframe as temp table, unable to execute select statement due to error table does not exist.

```
val schemaRDD = StructType(
    StructField("SessionCount", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("SampleTime", TimestampType, false) ::
    StructField("Program_ID", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)

  var sessionTrend = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schemaRDD)

val run_id_q= new Queue[Int]  


for (i <- 1 to 10)
{
     run_id_q += i
    sessionTrend = sessionTrend.unionAll(DF2)  // DF2 is a data set with same schema as sessionTrend 
    if (run_id_q.length >=3) {
      v_run_id = run_id_q.dequeue()
           sessionTrend = sessionTrend.filter(sessionTrend("run_id")>v_run_id)

    }

sessionTrend.show() // working fine and displaying expected result
sessionTrend.registerTempTable("memTBL")
val myData= hivecontext.sql("select * from memTBL") // ERROR: Table memTBL does not exit

}
```

any suggestion to solve this issue? Actually,I am trying to create a dataframe that will always have latest 3 records.

Thanks
Hossain

Comment: use `sqlcontext` because you created table on it. so accessing will be   `sqlcontext.sql("select * from memTBL")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your dataframe `sessionTrend`  was created from `sqlContext`

```
var sessionTrend = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schemaRDD)
```

and your trying to access the temp table using `hiveContext` . Either create your dataframe using `hiveContext` or access the table using sqlContext as shown below.

```
val myData= sqlContext.sql("select * from memTBL")
```

Basically, the point is you should be using either one for them for the operation and not intermix it.